# google action conversation exit: not waiting for user response

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to seek user feedback at the end of a google action session using actions sdk.

As per the Actions documentation (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits), I have set the cancel intent

```
   "conversations" : {
    ...
    "inDialogIntents": [
        {
          "name": "actions.intent.CANCEL"
        },
     ...
```

and in my functions code I am calling a `SimpleResponse` as below:

```
app.intent('actions.intent.CANCEL', (conv, input) => {
  conv.close(new SimpleResponse({
    speech: 'Kindly rate between 1 and 5,
    text: 'Rate between 1 and 5'
  }));
});
```

When the user says `goodbye`, the above code gets called. The speech is heard and text displayed but the conversation immediately exits with an earcon.

The documentation mentions that the system will wait for 2 seconds before exiting but it seems to do so immediately. Is there a way to get this working? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you'd like to achieve. First of all, as long as you're using `conv.close()` method, you are ending the conversation. If you want to keep the mic open, you need to use `conv.ask()` method. But I'm not sure id you can use `conv.ask()` with actions.intent.CANCEL, because that event is there to get the user out, not to keep the conversation going. But I'm not %100 sure, you need to try it.

If what you're trying to achieve is something like this:

> **User:** cancel
>
> **System:** How would you rate our interaction?
>
> **User:** Good.
>
> **earcon**

Then, in my humble opinion, you probably shouldn't (and as I said you probably can't) do it. The docs clearly state that the purpose for custom exit behavior is:

> to cleanup your fulfillment logic and respond to the user one last time.

Also, the docs doesn't say the system will wait for the user response for 2 second. It says the execution of the request (the time out for your fulfillment) is 2 seconds. Plus; if a user is canceling mid-conversation, chances are that the interaction was unsuccessful anyway. I'd rather create feedback dialog turns that are connected to the fallback intents and happy path(s).

Still, try to use `conv.ask()` instead and let me know if that works. (And please let me know by commenting.) Either case, though, I'd consider getting the feedback some other way.

Comment: Thanks @Yuksel Tolun for your comment. You rightly identified what I want to achieve. And yes, I misunderstood (misread) the 2 seconds interpretation. Yes, I could "ask" instead of "close" when the "goodbye" type of response is given but I guess I would need to perform an honourable exit ("close") if the user chooses to ignore. Let me figure that logic out. Thanks. Will vote your answer as correct.

Comment: Glad I could help.